# C literal suffix U, UL problems

Tags: c, literals

Could someone explain to me what can happen if I'll forget suffix(postfix) for constants(literals) in ANSI C?

For example I saw for bit shift operations such defines:

```
#define AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos (2UL) /*!< Position of NOTRESOLVED field. */
#define AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Msk (0x1UL << AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos) /*!< Bit mask of NOTRESOLVED field. */
#define AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Disabled (0UL) /*!< Interrupt disabled. */
#define AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Enabled (1UL) /*!< Interrupt enabled. */
#define AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Set (1UL) /*!< Enable interrupt on write. */
```

It's used in 32bit architecture. But it could be ported to 16bit or 8bit.
What can happen if postfix UL is not used and I'll use these macros for bit shift operations as it is supposed?

I just assume that e.g. in 8-bit architecture can (1<<30) leads to overflow.

**EDIT**: I have found nice link: http://dystopiancode.blogspot.cz/2012/08/constant-suffixes-and-prefixes-in-ansi-c.html

But is it safe to use suffixes if the code is supposed to be ported on various architectures?

For instance if suffix U represents unisgned int so for 8bit architecture it's usually 16bit but for 32bit it's 32bit variable, so 0xFFFFAAAAU is ok for 32bit compiler but not for 8bit compiler, right?

Comment: "8-bit architecture" does not equal "can only count up to 255". It's up to the compiler to translate all longer-than-bus-size calculations into chunks that can be digested more easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A decimal number like -1,1,2,12345678, etc. without any suffix will get the smallest type it will fit, starting with `int`, `long`, `long long`.

An octal or hex number like 0, 0123, 0x123, 0X123 without any suffix will get the smallest type it will fit, starting with `int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`.

---

The following is a potential problem should `AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos` exceed 31.   Note: `unsigned long` must be at *least* 32 bits.  It would result in 0 ** if `unsigned long` was 32 bits, but non-zero if longer.

```
(0x1UL << AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos)
```

The following is a similar potential problem should `AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos` exceed 15.  `0x1` is an `unsigned`, which must only be at least 16 bits.  Also if `unsigned/int` is 16 bits, the minimum, `0x1` will be `int`.  So without explicitly using `U`, `0x1` could be a problem if `AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos == 15`.  [@Matt McNabb]

```
(0x1 << AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Pos)
```

---

**Bitwise shift operators**
 "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." C11dr §6.5.7 3

---

Machine width is not the key issue.  An 8bit or 16bit machine could use 16, 32, etc. bit size `int`.  Again, 16 bit is the minimum size for a compliant C compiler.

---

[Edit] **
I should have said " It (shifting more than 31 bits) would result in Undefined behavior, **UB**, if `unsigned long` was 32 bits."

Comment: OK... `0x1 << 15` also causes UB (signed integer overflow) if `int` is 16-bit, so "exceed 15" should be "equal or exceed 15" or similar

Comment: @Matt McNabb Thanks for pointing out that error too - corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It can break.

It might be better to include the cast in the code itself, i.e.

```
uint32_t something = (uint32_t) AAR_INTENSET_NOTRESOLVED_Set << 30;
```

This makes it work even if the `#define` for the constant is simply an integer.