# How should a 64-bit integer literal be represented in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm puzzled by a difference in behavior between MSVC and clang for this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
  int64_t wat = -2147483648;
  std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << wat << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013 (on Windows 7) all display:

```
0x80000000
```

But clang 503.0.40 (on OSX) displays:

```
0xffffffff80000000
```

What is the correct behavior according to the C++ standard? Should the literal be zero-extended or sign-extended to 64 bits?

I'm aware that `int64_t wat = -2147483648LL;` will lead to that same result on both compilers, but I wonder about the proper behavior without the literal suffix.

Comment: I have a feeling this changed in C++11 to give the more sensible behaviour you're seeing above with clang - I'm sure a language lawyer will be along soon to quote chapter and verse...

Comment: @Paul R: The "non-sensible" behavior existed only in C89/90, where the compiler had to try `int`, `long int` and the `unsigned long int`. The inclusion of unsigned type was a bad decision, which was abandoned in C099 and in the very first version of C++ (C++98). Now the compiler has to try only signed types, in order of increasing width. In this case the only difference of C++11 is the addition of `long long int`. It is purely quantitative.

Comment: OK - thanks - maybe I was getting mixed up between C and C++. FWIW I always add the explicit suffix anyway, so never have to think about what the behaviour should be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The type on the left of the initialization does not matter. The expression `-2147483648` is interpreted by itself, independently.

Literal `2147483648` has no suffixes, which means that the compiler will first make an attempt to interpret it as an `int` value. On your platform `int` is apparently a 32-bit type. Value `2147483648` falls outside the range of signed 32-bit integer type. The compiler is required to use wider signed integer type to represent the value, if one is available (in the `int`, `long int`, `long long int` sequence, with the last one being formally available from C++11 on). But if no sufficiently wide signed integer type is available, the behavior is undefined

In MSVC historically `long int` has the same width as `int`, albeit 64-bit `long long int` is also supported in later versions of MSVC. However, even in VS2013 (which supports `long long int`) I get

```
warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
```

in response to your initialization. This means that MSVC still sticks to archaic C89/90 rules of integer literal interpretation (where types were chosen from `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int` sequence).

Note that MSVC is not officially a C++11 compiler. So formally it does not have to try `long long int`. Such type does not formally exist in pre-C++11 language. From that point of view, MSVC has no sufficiently large signed integer type to use in this case and the behavior is undefined. Within the freedom provided by undefined behavior, the use of C89/90 rules for integer literal interpretation is perfectly justifiable.

You might also take a look at this [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c/14695202#14695202)

Comment: I think it depends on whether you're compiling as C++11 or not?

Comment: @Paul R: How? Since C++98 "suffixless" integer literals had to be tried for `int` and `long int`. In MSVC both normally have the same width.

Comment: The command line I'm using for MSVC is `cl wat.cpp /EHsc`, so no special flags other than the one for exception handling. I don't think there is a C++11 flag in MSVC.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I think there was an SO question on this very subject within the last few days - I'll see if I can find it...

Comment: OK - here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605777/c-literal-postfix-u-ul-problems/25606226#25606226 - I was evidently thinking about C, not C++ - sorry for the noise...

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for the information about the warning. When I use `/Wall` on the command line I see it. Here is the MSDN page for that warning; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kh09110.aspx

Comment: @Josh Peterson: I retract my assertion that this is a bug in MSVC. It would be a bug in C++11 compiler, but MSVC is not officially a C++11 compiler yet. From the pre-C++11 point of view the MSVC's behavior is formally legal.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question about how a 64-bit literal should be represented. Unless that wasn't the OP's question, in which case, the question title should be changed to fit.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think this does answer the question. In C++11, a 64-bit integer literal should be represented using a `long long int`. Thanks to warning C4146 we know that, MSVC is instead using `unsigned long int` which is a valid choice for a pre-C++11 compiler.